# Convergence of doubly indexed sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My question is about the convergence of two-dimensional arrays of reals. What I mean by a two-dimensional array is a mapping on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_{n,l}$ be such a mapping, i.e. $(n,l) \mapsto x_{n,l}$. I would like to prove the following statement.

Suppose that for each fixed $l \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_{n,l} \to x_l$ for some real number $x_l$. Suppose further that $x_l \to x$ as $l \to \infty$ for some real number $x$. Then there exists a subsequence $(l_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n,l_n} \to x$.

I am not sure if the proof should include explicit construction of the subsequence $l_n$. But I feel like it should.
So, then I have

$$\forall{l} \in \mathbb{N},\varepsilon >0 \quad \exists{N(l,\varepsilon)} \text{  such that } \lvert x_{n,l} - x_l\rvert < \varepsilon \quad \forall{n \geq N(l,\varepsilon)}$$

$$\forall{\varepsilon>0} \quad \exists{M(\varepsilon)} \text{  such that } \lvert x_{l} - x\rvert < \varepsilon \quad \forall{l \geq M(\varepsilon)}$$

(If $\sup_l N(l,\varepsilon) < \infty$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$, then of course I wouldn't even have to construct a subsequence. That would be the uniform convergence case but that is not what I have.)

By the triangle inequality I have

$$\lvert x_{n,l_n} -x \rvert \leq \lvert x_{n,l_n} - x_{l_n} \rvert + \lvert x_{l_n} -x \rvert$$

I can make the second term on the RHS as small as I want for any subsequence $l_n$. If I can say the same about the first term on the RHS for some subsequence $l_n$, I will be done of course. But I don't see how to do that. I am also not sure if this is the way to go. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So $l_n$ is a subsequence of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @zhw. Yes. (I guess so at least since the term subsequence is used in the statement of the problem)

Comment: So then $l_n\ge n$ for all $n$?

Comment: @zhw.  yes, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we define $x_{nl}=0$ for $l>n/2,$ $x_{nl}=1$ otherwise. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{nl}= 1$ for each $l.$ So $x=1.$ But for any subsequence $l_n$ of $\mathbb N,$ we must have $l_n \ge n.$ This implies $x_{nl_n} =0$ for every $n.$ It seems like the result fails.

Comment: I think I understood your example but I should be able to choose the path $(2n,n)$ to move along. I know that this contradicts what I said earlier but I think there is something wrong in the phrasing of this question (I copied it from a set of lecture notes). If I were to construct a subsequence $(n_l)_{l \geq 0}$, would the result then be correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be the natural result here. For each $l$ we have $|x_{nl}-x_l|<1/l$ for all sufficiently large $n.$ That will allow you to choose the the subsequence $n_l.$

Comment: Can you write your solution in the answer in a bit more explicit form so that I can accept it?